# How to list down hidden files using a .BAT File?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

For my computer project, my teacher requires us to make a bat file that lists down hidden files. The whole class doesn't know how though. Here is my code so far:

```
@echo off
set /p UserInput=What directory would you like?
cd %UserInput%
dir /S /aH
Pause
```

My teacher says I'm almost done, I'm just missing 2 or 3 characters 
after "dir /S /aH". Would anyone know what these missing characters are?

Hi guys, I'm sorry for the late reply. We're having so many projects before the semester ends. :( When I run the bat file, it shows the following.. Here's the link: [imgur.com/W4Wm4vP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mse01.jpg)

Comment: Something like this? `dir /S /aH > list.txt`

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `dir /?` to get displayed the help for this command and read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). You can run any Windows command with `/?` as parameter in a command prompt window to get help on it. There is also the command __HELP__ which lists the commands.

Comment: If he wants **files only** (no directory) you might need [`dir /S /aH-D`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)

Comment: One little thing though: don't forget to surround paths with double quotes as they might contain spaces: `cd %userinput%`

Comment: Hi guys, I'm sorry for the late reply. We're having so many projects before the semester ends. :(

When I run the bat file, it shows the following:

What directory would you like?d
The system cannot find the path specified.
      Volume in drive C has no label.
      Volume Serial Number is 8061-99F6

       Directory of C:\Users\admin\Desktop

It then it lists down the files of my desktop. Would you know what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry for the messy comment, you might find it more convenient to see a picture of the cmd. Here's the link:

http://imgur.com/W4Wm4vP

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you've already received responses that are sufficient to your initial request, I've added one just to show that you should really try to perform some sort of verification of user input before proceeding with your listing:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
CLS
SET /P "UserInput=What directory would you like? "
IF "%UserInput%"=="" GOTO LOOP
IF /I NOT "%CD%"=="%UserInput%" (PUSHD "%UserInput%" 2>NUL||GOTO LOOP)
DIR /B /S /AH-D
TIMEOUT /T -1 /NOBREAK
```

*I trust this will give you a few more things to research and learn.*

**Edit**
As an after thought, if the end user is inputting only a directory name and not a full path then you may need to replace line six with:

```bat
FOR %%A IN ("%CD%") DO IF /I NOT "%%~nxA"=="%UserInput%" (
    PUSHD "%UserInput%" 2>NUL||GOTO LOOP)
```

Comment: Hi @Compo , I'm sorry for the late reply. We're having so many projects before the semester ends. :( When I run the bat file, it shows the following.. Here's the link: imgur.com/W4Wm4vP

Comment: You haven't provided a full path so I assume that you have replaced line six as in the edit and that you have input a genuine directory name relative to your current directory. If `d` is a drive letter and not a directory, then you need to complete it, _a drive is not a single character._